# Tic Tac Toe Java GUI setting up playing field

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am currently working on coding a simple version of Tic Tac Toe in Java GUI. I am having a problem with setting up the playing field. A button represents a square which a player can press to either get "X" or "O".

```
 //Playing field class

 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import java.awt.Color;
 class TicTacToeFrame extends JFrame {
     private JFrame game = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
     private JPanel pane1, pane2, pane3;
     Button button = new Button();
     public TicTacToeFrame() {
         game.setSize(300, 300);
         game.setVisible(true);
         game.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

         pane1 = new JPanel();
         pane2 = new JPanel();
         pane3 = new JPanel();

         add(pane1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
         add(pane2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         add(pane3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

         pane1.setBackground(Color.white);
         pane2.setBackground(Color.white);
         pane3.setBackground(Color.white);

         placeButton();
     }
     public void placeButton() {
         for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
             if (i < 4) {
                 pane1.add(button.getButton());
             }
             else if (3 < i && i < 7) {
                 pane2.add(button.getButton());
             }
             else if (6 < i && i < 10) {
                 pane3.add(button.getButton());
             }
         }
     }
 }

 //Button class

 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 public class Button {
     private JButton button;
     private int number = 0;
     private String player;
     public Button() {
         button = new JButton();
     }
     public String getPlayer() {
         return player;
     }
     public JButton getButton() {
         return button;
     }
     public void changePlayer() {
         for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
              if (number % 2 == 0) {
                  player = "X";
              }
              else {
                  player = "O";
              }
              number++;
         }
     }
 }
```

When I run the program in a main I receive the frame, however, the buttons which are supposed to represent squares are not placed. Help?

Comment: add the panes after you add the buttons to them and show the board once everything has been created and added to the frame, also try repainting the frame

Comment: You're only adding **one** JButton to the whole grid, since your call to `getButton()` returns that one single button. You need to create a new JButton for each spot that needs it, and you're not doing this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"You're only adding one JButton to the whole grid"* Close hombre, but no sombrero. `Button button = new Button();` OP: that should be `JButton button = new JButton();` (but use 9 buttons, one for each of the 9 squares). **Edit:** D'Oh! had not realised the OP had a class `Button` that extended `JButton`. :P OP: Another good reason not to use the name of an existing class for a custom class.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you wrap a JFrame (game) inside a class that already extends JFrame?

I'd do it in this way:

```
public TicTacToeFrame() {
    super("Tic Tac Toe");
    //I prefer to call pack() method in this case..
    //setSize(300, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    pane1 = new JPanel();
    pane2 = new JPanel();
    pane3 = new JPanel();

    add(pane1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(pane2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(pane3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    pane1.setBackground(Color.white);
    pane2.setBackground(Color.white);
    pane3.setBackground(Color.white);

    placeButton();
    //call setVisible after you added all the buttons
    setVisible(true);
    pack();
}
```

There is a mistake also in `placeButton` method (as noticed by Hovercraft Full Of Eels):

```
public void placeButton() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        //You should create the button all the time
        Button button = new Button();
        if (i < 4) {
            pane1.add(button.getButton());
        }
        else if (3 < i && i < 7) {
            pane2.add(button.getButton());
        }
        else if (6 < i && i < 10) {
            pane3.add(button.getButton());
        }
    }
}
```